# After using some larger list of words with Pygoogle, I get "'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable"

Tags: python

I am trying to get number of hits for a larger list of words (>500), with Pygoogle
(from: http://code.google.com/p/pygoogle/):

```
 g = pygoogle(<some request>)
 freq = g.get_result_count()
```

Now, after starting success, probably around 200th request, I start to get only "'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable". Is this Google stuff, some kind of protection, or what? In principle, how can I get number of hits from Google for a large list of words?

Many thanks!
PM

Comment: I would assume google blocks you after spamming them.

Comment: I thought so. Nevertheless, how can I get number of hits for larger list of words?